# Ideals of Lattice.

Tags: ideals, lattice-orders

If $L$ is a lattice then the ideal $I$ of $L$ is a nonempty lower segment closed under join. I need to show that the set of ideals $I(L)$ of $L$ forms a lattice under $\subseteq$

I know the construction of join in case the ideals are of the ring. ($i_{1} + i_{2}$ from $I_1$ and $I_2$). But I cant figure out a similar definition of join for Ideals of Lattices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe $I(L)$ is closed under intersection. This yields the meet. If $A,B\in I(L)$ then consider the intersection of all ideals containing $A\cup B$ (which is nonempty since $A\cup B\subseteq L\in I(L)$).

More generally, any semilattice which is complete with respect to one lattice operation can have the other lattice operation defined in this way, making it a (not just semi) lattice.

Comment: I really liked the way you defined the "smallest Ideal" containing $A$ union $B$. But here we side stepped  explicitely writing the structure of this new Lattice. Like in case of normal groups forming a Lattice we take $HK$ to be the join and we know how each element in $HK$ looks like. Can we have similar characterization for $I(L)$

Comment: @Anurag Intuitively, given $X\subseteq L$, the smallest ideal of $I(L)$ containing $X$ should be obtained by first adjoining all its finite joins and then adjoining all lower segments to it. I'd have to check a bit more to make sure.

Comment: Okay... You seem to be an expert in this field. Are you a profesor or a graduate student ?

Comment: @Anurag No, I am an advanced undergrad with a cursory familiarity with order theory.

Answer (score 2):

If a lattice is finite, then ideals are *principal*, which means that they are generated by a single element, i.e., they have the following form:
$$\downarrow a:=\{x\in L:x\leqslant a\}.$$

Consequently, join and meet are given as follows:

$$(\downarrow a)\otimes(\downarrow b)=\,\downarrow(a\wedge b),$$

$$(\downarrow a)\oplus(\downarrow b)=\,\downarrow (a\vee b).$$

Obviously, then $L\cong I(L)$.

For infinite lattices there are some results,... to be continued (if you want).